# JS: How to stop a function from looping while the other function inside of it is executing?

Tags: javascript, function

In my project, I extract the feature points from a streaming video in function F1 and if some of them match with the data from the database I need to start the other function F2 inside F1. However, F2 cannot execute until the end because F1 keeps updating the input data to F2, so it just doesn't have enough time. Can I stop F1 from running while F2 is processing the data?

In my code I use tracking.js and OpenCV.js packages. First I run the video stream and for each frame  I do next: 
("corners2" and "descriptors2" are the data from the database)

```
function f1 (){

   context2d.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas2d.width, canvas2d.height);
   src1.data.set(context2d.getImageData(0, 0, canvas2d.width, canvas2d.height).data);

   var blur1 = tracking.Image.blur(src1.data, canvas2d.width, canvas2d.height, blurRadius);
   var gray1 = tracking.Image.grayscale(blur1, canvas2d.width, canvas2d.height);
   var corners1 = tracking.Fast.findCorners(gray1, canvas2d.width, canvas2d.height);
   var descriptors1 = tracking.Brief.getDescriptors(gray1, canvas2d.width, corners1);

   cv.imshow("outputCanvas2d", src1);

   const FPS = 30;
   let begin = Date.now()
   let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
   setTimeout(f1, delay); 

   f2(corners1,descriptors1);

   function f2(corners1,descriptors1) {

       var matches = tracking.Brief.reciprocalMatch(corners1, descriptors1, corners2, descriptors2);

       matches.sort(function(a, b) {
           return b.confidence - a.confidence;
       });

       if (matches.length > 50){
           window.app = new App(); 
       } else {
           console.log("not enought keypoints")
           var matches = []
       }
   }
}
setTimeout(f1, 0);
```

From F2, if I have enough matches, I want to start an AR session by calling `window.app = new App();` It starts but then it gives an error `Cannot create an XRWebGLLayer with a lost WebGL context.` I assume that it is due to the fact that F1 keeps running at the same time while it tries to start the AR session.

Sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing, I am quite new to JS and just try to make it work. Thank you for help.

Comment: This is a perfect motive to learn async & await, If you write the code I can rewrite it for you working in parallel (both functions will execute)

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so we can see what needs to be corrected

Comment: I just added the code.

Answer (score 0):

The examples will use this [JSONPlacerholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/) & [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) as the purpose of this example is to illustrate awaits/asyncs & not requests, be sure to try them first

```
const f1 = async (params) => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/').then(
    ).then((res) => {
        console.log('f1')
    });
};

const f2 = async (params) => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/').then(
    ).then((res) => {
        console.log('f2')
    });
};

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    f1();
    f2();
    // results will appear interferring as f1 will run & we won't wait till it finishes, instead
    // the code will continue to f2 then won't wait for it to finish & then loop again 
}
```

if you want to wait for one of them to finish, use await f1() to block all code untill f1() finishes, be sure to save it in a variable if it returns smth

Just two normal functions with the word async before the params, for more [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)